# HTML in database

Tags: html, database, character-encoding, ascii

My website has a wysiwyg editor- logged in users save text to an SQL database.

When I retrieve this text later- there are occasional malformed characters.
For instance an HTML bullet point (which I suspect is an `<ul>` and `<li>` tag)
- comes out as a question mark in a black diamond.

Is the wysiwyg editor spitting out bad code?  I did use nicEdit- I know tinyMCE is better,
but nicEdit is really light-weight.  I'll switch if I have to.

Or should I run the text through some kind of filter function?

My pages are build w/ PHP- any idea how I can fix this bug?

Comment: Sounds like special characters aren't being converted into their respective html entities before entering the database.

Comment: The page has a charset of UTF 8.  The SQL database field where the data is saved is type "text" with Collation :utf8_general_ci

Comment: @Jrod  Do i use the php HTMLEntities() to do this?

Comment: So check what is being inputted in the database, and what is printed once you retrieved it. Is it valid xhtml then your problem isn't with the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably do both:

a) switch to a Wysiwyg editor that produces valid xhtml to start with, and

b) parse/validate/sanitize whatever is being sent by the end-users (using html purifier, php's dom library, or other) before storing it.